# Can we have consistent theories stating opposing provability statements that are non-standardly coded?

Tags: lo.logic, proof-theory, formal-proof

I want to coin a notion of "strong provability", to be defined as:

$S$ is strongly provable in $T$ if and only if there is a Gödel code of its proof in $T$ that is strictly smaller than any Gödel code of a proof of its negation in $T$

Formally:

$ S \text { is strongly provable in } T \iff \\ \exists x: \operatorname {Proof}_T(x, \ulcorner S \urcorner ) \land  \forall y (\operatorname {Proof}_T (y, \operatorname {neg}(\ulcorner S \urcorner)) \implies x < y ) $

Now let $T \vdash S$ be the usual metatheoretic statement of $S$ being syntactically proved from $T$

Then is it provable that:

$(T\vdash S) \iff S \text { is strongly provable in } T$

The forward direction is clear, but the opposite is what irks me? Can we have a sentence whose smallest code of its proof (not the metatheoretic) is a non-standard natural, and every proof of its negations is strictly lager than it? I mean in this case it'll be indeterminate syntactically speaking, and the statements would be false, yet is this possible, can we have a theory that spells that and be consistent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This idea in play here is due to Rosser and is the main idea behind the [Gödel-Rosser theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosser%27s_trick).

Specifically, Rosser proposes to consider the sentence $\rho$ asserting that for every proof of $\rho$ in PA, there is a smaller proof of $\neg\rho$. In your terminology, $\rho$ asserts its own non-strong-provability. Such a sentence can be constructed by the fixed-point lemma. The conclusion is that if PA is consistent, then $\rho$ is independent of PA. It cannot be provable, since then it would have a proof of some specific length, and PA would prove that some smaller number would be a proof of $\neg\rho$, but by consistency none of those numbers can actually code a proof. And it cannot be refutable, since then $\neg\rho$ would have a proof of some specific length, and so PA would have to prove that one of the smaller numbers is a proof of $\rho$, which again can't happen by consistency.

The forward direction of your biconditional, which you say is "clear", is false if $T$ is inconsistent, since $T$ will prove every $S$, but it will not strongly prove every $S$. Meanwhile, the converse direction is true, since if a statement is strongly provable, it is provable.

Meanwhile, regarding the issues in your final paragraph, it may be interesting to consider the case of the Rosser sentence. In some models of PA, there is a proof of $\rho$ that is smaller than any proof of $\neg\rho$; and in other models of PA, there is a proof of $\neg\rho$ that is smaller than any proof of $\rho$. In both cases, those proofs are nonstandard, since $\rho$ is actually independent of PA.

Comment: Your last paragraph contradicts the sentence just before it. This means that the biconditional is not true in both directions. However, if we assume that T
 is consistent, then just the forward direction is true, the other direction is falsified by the models of PA in your last paragraph. I think, if we assume that T is $\omega$-consistent, then we get both directions true.

Comment: The statement just before is a statement in the metatheory, that if a statement is strongly provable, then in particular, it is provable. This is obvious, since part of what it means to be strongly provable is to be provable, but furthermore in a certain way. The last paragraph, in contrast, is about the internal notions of provability of the Rosser sentence, and in those models I mention, in fact everything is provable---the only question is whether $\rho$ or $\neg\rho$ has the smaller proof. And the independence of $\rho$ means it can happen either way.

Comment: No! I was speaking about the biconditional, on the left is the syntactic (metatheoretic) provability, while on the right is the notion of strong provability which is a theoretic statement, what I mean is that the right to left direction of the biconditional doesn't hold, because the models of PA you spoke about in your last paragraph shows that you can have $\rho$ being strongly provable (in a theoretic sense) yet not syntactically (metatheoretically) provable.

Comment: Strong provability is also a metatheoretic statement, which is the same as interpreting the theoretic statement in the standard model. That is how I am reading your biconditional. What is true in some nonstandard models has nothing to do with the biconditional, which doesn't refer to any nonstandard models.

Comment: Well *strong provability* as defined here is not a metatheoretic statement, it becomes equivalent to the metatheoretic syntactical notion of provability in the standard model yes, but not in all models. In the models you spoke about it appears that one can state strong provability of a sentence (like $\rho$ or like $\neg \rho$) yet without being able to prove it syntactically. I read the biconditional *externally* as the existence of a standard natural coding a proof of the sentence in T (on the left) and on the right we have strong provability allowing non-standards, so R to L direction fails

Comment: .continuation, ..along this external reading of the biconditional, I meant to say that even if we say that some statement is coded by a number that is lower than all codes of its negation, still all codes (of both statements) can be non-standard, and it doesn't entail that the lesser coded sentence (i.e. the strongly provable one) must have a standard natural coding it. That's what I wanted to say. That's what I mean when I say that the biconditional fails from right to left.

Comment: You seem to want to interpret the right hand side of your biconditional in a model, but you haven't specified which model. If I assume the RHS of your biconditional, what am I assuming?

Comment: The problem is in the left hand side. I'll try spell matters differently. Lets fix T to be PA, now to the language of PA, add $\vdash$ as some logical dyadic primitive, also add $T$ as a primitive constant denoting a theory. Now add an axiom scheme stating that for every axiom $A_i $(whether logical or extra-logical) of PA we have $T \vdash A_i$ and also add modus ponens over $\vdash$, that is, $(T \vdash A) \land (T \vdash (A \to B)) \to (T\vdash B)$. Write the biconditional we are speaking about in those terms. Now, is the R to L direction of the biconditional satisfied in all models of PA?

Comment: My answer (which might be wrong) is that the non-standard model of PA you spoke about at the last paragraph will falsify the R to L direction of the biconditional.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the sentences $A;B$ used in the modus ponens axiom must not be using $T$ nor $\vdash$

Comment: To answer your comment we are assuming PA.

Comment: The concept of strong provability is interesting/robust, and this is what my answer addresses. Any strongly provable sentence is of course provable (and has no smaller proof of the negation), by definition. This is true in any model of PA for the formalized versions of provability and strong provability. However, being provable in a model, or strongly provable, does not imply provable in the metatheory, since there are models of $\neg$Con(PA). All that is totally clear. Your treatment of the issue, unfortunately, seems confused about basic issues, which I presume is the cause of the downvotes.